# Discerning whether these two definitions of primitive polynomial are indeed equivalent

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

During my studies of Rings and Fields, I came across with two different statements of what a primitive polynomial is:

> (R): A polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x+a_{0} \in R[x]$,
> where $R$ is a UFD is *primitive* if 1 is a greatest common divisor of
> its coefficients (that is, the only common divisors of its
> coefficients are units)

and

> (V-P): If $R$ is a commutative ring, a  polynomial
> $f(x)=a_nx^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x+a_{0} \in R[x]$ is *primitive* if the ideal of R
> generated by its coefficientes is equal to the whole ring R.

(where (R) is the definition I found on Rotman "Abstract Algebra", while (V-P) is the
definition of the book "Teoría de Cuerpos y Teoría de Galois" by Viola Prioli).

Of course, in the first definiton we require the ring of coefficients to be a UFD so that the greatest common divisor of elements of the ring do exists, while the second seems to be more general.

Now, I'm wondering if, when taking the ring $R$ in the second definition as a UFD too, the two statements above are equivalent.

---

What I've done so far:

**(V-P) $\Rightarrow$ (R)]** Let $f(x)=a_nx^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x+a_{0} $ be such that $R= < a_{0}, \dots , a_{n}>$. Since
$R$ is a UFD, there exists $d$ a greatest common divisor of the elements $a_{0}, \dots , a_{n}$
of $R$. Since $1 \in  < a_{0}, \dots , a_{n}>$, we can find $\lambda_{0} , \dots , \lambda_{n}$
in $R$ such that
$$1=a_{0}\lambda_{0} + \cdots + a_{n}\lambda_{n}.$$
Since $d | a_{i}$ for all index $i$, we conclude that $d$ divides 1, i.e. $d$ is a unit.

**(R) $\Rightarrow$ (V-P)] (when the UFD in question is a PID)**
Let $f(x)=a_nx^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x+a_{0} \in R[x]$ be such that 1 is a gcd of its coefficients.
Let the ideal

$$I=< a_{0}, \dots , a_{n}> = <a_{0}> + \cdots + <a_{n}>;$$
since $R$ is a PID, there exists $d \in I$ such that $I=<d>$. Now, each $a_{i}$ is an element
of $I$, so $d | a_{i}$ for all index $i$, that is, $d$ is a common divisor of all the $a_{i}$'s; thus $d | 1$, i.e. $d$ is a unit. Therefore, $I=R$.

**My question:** is it true in general (not only when the UFD is a PID) that (R) implies (V-P) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this isn't true in general. For example, let's take $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The coefficients of the polynomial $xy+2\in R[y]$ are $x$ and $2$, and their greatest common divisor in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is indeed $1$. However, the ideal $(2,x)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[x]$ contains only the polynomials which have an even free coefficient, so it is not the whole ring.

Comment: Wonderful example ! Thank you very much !